# Как узнать директорию в которой лежит программа?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно узнать путь к моей программе, и в последующем ликвидировать её.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991933/get-path-for-my-exe ну или вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application

Comment: Ликвидировать? Рубите сук на котором сидите?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что процесс, который будет "ликвидировать директорию", должен быть запущен из другого места?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Касательно самоликвидации:

Как выше отметили, пока программа работает она удалиться не может, НО ничего не мешает запустить *.Bat из программы перед ее закрытием удалить.

А еще можно воспользоваться [`MoveFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) и файл будет вычищен системой после ребута.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно написали в комментариях выше, получить путь (включая имя исполняемого файла) можно так

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Только путь, без исполняемого файла будет так :

```
string s = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

А вот удалить программа сама себя не сможет, скажет что процесс занят другим приложением )

Comment: _Текущий рабочий каталог_ может отличаться от папки, откуда была запущена программа.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не знал об этом.

Comment: [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18727692/5045688)