# Как создать файл в директории

Tags: c#

Я в программе узнаю директорию в какой расположен исполняемый файл программы, как создать в ней текстовый файл?

```
string linkFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

Comment: уверен на 99.9% что ответ на этот вопрос есть на ru.so

Comment: Смотрите классы File, Path, FileStream и т.д. - это "избитая" тема

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как узнать директорию в которой лежит программа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666649/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041505/3129992

Comment: Среднестатистический пользователь не имеет прав доступа к этой папке. Поэтому программа без прав админа не сможет создать в ней файл.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, вообще-то исполняемый файл необязательно находится в `Program Files`, так что в общем случае это не так.

Comment: @freim - да, я знаю. Но готов поспорить, что топикстартер пока слабо разбирается в правах доступа и т. п. Поэтому лучше сразу ему объяснить, куда правильнее помещать файлы. (ЗЫ: кто объяснит? мне лень...)

Answer (score 1):

using System.IO;
...
File.Create(path);
Где path это путь по которому нужно создать файл.